# Mysterious multiple execution issue in vb.net/windows server

Tags: vb.net, smtp, windows-server-2008, batch-processing

I’ve been trouble shooting this issue for the past two weeks now and I’m about at my wits end. I’ve got it narrowed down about as far as I can go and am really posting this in hope that someone can confirm my analysis and possibly suggest a course of action.

I will walk through what is going on up to this point in the application so that we are all on the same page. The application was written to query a database and retrieve three random records containing user information and a user email address, then for each record returned we check to see what the type is and send an email based on the type. I have tested this process locally and it executes without issue every time, yet once this is compiled into an executable and placed on a server to be executed at an interval of every 15 minutes, users have started to complain about receiving multiple emails for the same record….I will post some of the code and then explain what I have found up to this point:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    CreateExecutionLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToString, "BEGIN")

    Dim dtEmails As DataTable = RetreiveEmailsToSend()

    For Each dr As DataRow In dtEmails.Rows
        With dr
            Select Case .Item("EmailType").ToString.Trim
                Case "NEW"
                    SendNewEmail(.Item("EmpUserID").ToString.Trim, .Item("EmpEmailAddress").ToString.Trim, .Item("EmpFullName").ToString.Trim, _
                                       CInt(.Item("RecordIDPK").ToString.Trim), .Item("SupervisorEmailAddress").ToString.Trim)
                Case "24H"
                    Send24hEmail(.Item("EmpUserID").ToString.Trim, .Item("EmpEmailAddress").ToString.Trim, .Item("EmpFullName").ToString.Trim, _
                                       CInt(.Item("RecordIDPK").ToString.Trim), .Item("SupervisorEmailAddress").ToString.Trim)
                Case "48H"
                    Send48hEmail(.Item("EmpUserID").ToString.Trim, .Item("EmpEmailAddress").ToString.Trim, .Item("EmpFullName").ToString.Trim, _
                                       CInt(.Item("RecordIDPK").ToString.Trim), .Item("SupervisorEmailAddress").ToString.Trim)
            End Select
            UpdateRecordAfterEmail(CInt(.Item("RecordIDPK").ToString.Trim), .Item("EmailType").ToString.Trim)
        End With
    Next

    CreateExecutionLogFile(DateTime.Now.ToString, "END")

End Sub

''Send24hEmail() and Send48hEmail() are mirrors of this function with only the wording in the email body being changed
''therefore I only include the following function to make things easier to read in this post
Private Sub SendNewEmail(ByVal EmpUserID As String, ByVal EmpEmailAddress As String, ByVal EmpFullName As String, ByVal RecordID As Integer, ByVal SupEmailAddress As String)
    Dim strFrom As String = "DoNotReply@test.place"
    Dim strTo As String = EmpEmailAddress
    Dim strSubject As String = "TEST SUBJECT"
    Dim strCC As String = SupEmailAddress.Trim
    Dim strMessage As New StringBuilder

    With strMessage
        .Append("Hello!//EMAIL BODY IS BUILT HERE")
        .Append(DateTime.Now.ToString())
    End With

    SendEmail(strFrom, strTo, strSubject, strMessage.ToString, strCC, RecordID.ToString, "NEW", EmpUserID)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateRecordAfterEmail(ByVal RecordID As Integer, ByVal EmailType As String)
    'Connects to database and runs query to update the record as sent
End Sub

Public Sub SendEmail(ByVal strFrom As String, ByVal strTo As String, ByVal strSubject As String, ByVal strMessage As String, ByVal strCC As String, ByVal recordID As String, ByVal type As String, ByVal userID As String)
    If CheckIfEmailSent(recordID, type) = False Then
        If strTo > "" Then
            Try
                Dim MailMsg As New MailMessage()
                strTo = strTo.Trim(CChar(","))

                MailMsg.To.Add(strTo)

                If strCC.Trim <> "" Then
                    MailMsg.CC.Add(strCC)
                End If

                MailMsg.From = New MailAddress(strFrom, "FROM MESSAGE")
                MailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default
                MailMsg.Subject = strSubject.Trim()
                MailMsg.Body = strMessage.Trim() & vbCrLf
                MailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High
                MailMsg.IsBodyHtml = False

                Dim mailClient As New SmtpClient("mail.name.place")
                mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
                mailClient.Send(MailMsg)
                MailMsg.Dispose()

                CreateLogFile(recordID, type, userID, strTo)

            Catch innerException As Exception

                Dim MailMsg As New MailMessage()

                MailMsg.To.Add("nullReference@name.place")

                MailMsg.From = New MailAddress(strFrom, "FROM MESSAGE - ERROR")
                MailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default
                MailMsg.Subject = strSubject.Trim()
                MailMsg.Body = strMessage.Trim() & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & innerException.Message
                MailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High
                MailMsg.IsBodyHtml = False

                Dim mailClient As New SmtpClient("mail.name.place")
                mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
                mailClient.Send(MailMsg)
                MailMsg.Dispose()

            End Try
        End If
    Else
        CreateLogFile("*ERROR* ATTEMPTED RESEND" + " " + recordID, type, userID, strTo)
    End If

End Sub

Private Function CheckIfEmailSent(recordID As Integer, type As String) As Boolean
    ''Connect to database determine if recordID has already been sent
    ''If it has return true, else return false
End Function

Private Sub CreateLogFile(ByVal recordID, ByVal type, ByVal userID, ByVal email)
    ''Create log file on server containing information passed to function and
    ''current datetime
End Sub

Private Sub CreateExecutionLogFile(time As String, beginEnd As String)
    ''Create log file on server containing the time passed and either "BEGIN"
    ''or "END" depending on the value in "beginEnd"
End Sub

End Module
```

I had originally placed a patch inside the SendEmail() routine (CheckIfEmailSent()) that connected to the database and checked to see if the record had already been marked as sent before it sent another email. I figured this would quickly resolve the issue but I was soon proven wrong.

Now since the issue persisted after the above patch I started to think that it had something to do with the smtp mail client getting hung up and sending multiple emails, but then I realized that this wasn’t the case because the times that were included in the emails were different, meaning that the SendNewEmail() function would have had to ran twice to generate the new time value to place in the body string of the email before it was sent to the SendEmail() function….0_0….yeah….

The log file that is written to every time an email is sent only shows that the first email was sent and never logs a second…even more strange.
At this point the only thing I can think is happening is that somehow the process is being executed twice from the server once initially and then once again while the initial process is still running and somehow they are conflicting??? I’m at a loss….If anyone could shed some insight into what could be happening it would more or less make my month! :/

Comment: Too troubleshoot I would check/set an external flag that indicated a send was in process. If the flag is set I'd bail (preventing the multiple messages) and log some diagnostic info I'd gather to try and figure out how I got here. Making application log entries at critical points may also be useful.

Comment: Possible scenario (but not too probable): .Send causes an exception but sends an email, exception mail to nullReference@name.place is not sent (or received) but causes an exception so the program ends and database is not updated.

Comment: How long does it take to run and how often is it running? Completely stumped. Even if your final idea was true, why would it not write to the log the second time. That is the thing that I dont get. Has to be something the the email server. Is it the same server in both cases? Can you add something to the email message that will distinctly identify each email? `Guid.NewGuid.ToString`

Comment: @Steve I have an execution log which also only catalogs the first time through and the whole process executes within 1 - 4 seconds. The way the mail servers are setup there are multiples and each time an a request is sent out a different server sends the email in a "Round Robin" type scenario (which makes little to no sense to me but that's how they decided to set it up). The thing that makes me wonder if it could be the mail servers or not is the fact that the times in the email string are different...which would mean that it had to execute the function to build the email message body again

Comment: Is it 1 server that runs this process and decides which email server to use or is this process running on a bunch of different servers? KNowing that you have multiple servers, the time could be off on the servers and that why there is a difference in sent time.  Also, it could be the reason why it works fine and then about every 15 minutes it fails.  Maybe start logging which server the email is sent from and see if there is a pattern.

Comment: The file is setup to run every 15 minutes and executes successfully every 15 minutes within a time of 1-4 seconds. The datetime value that is displayed in the emails is converted to a string in the SendNewEmail() function before the mailserver knows about it...that's what throws me??? I like the idea of logging which webserver sent the message. I'll have to see about adding something for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tracking down which servers were sending the emails we finally tracked this issue down. What was going on was that there was an old version of the .exe set to run that everyone had forgotten about, and the two were conflicting with each other. Since they were setup to mark the rows as sent after sending, from time to time the old .exe would pull a record and send it right after the new one had ran BUT before it had a chance to mark it as already sent, thus producing duplicates for random records.